# Modal window don't work times to times in any browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I create application on ruby on rails and add modal window for login. I put modal code in partial layouts/header. I expect it must work on every page of my app but not. Modal don't open in home/index. It's start work on home/about. I don't understand why. I'll update my ask If needs code. Can anyone help me understand?

I try to move modal code on another pages but get same effect.

Answer (score -1):

- `home/index` and `home/about` is `URI`?
- Make sure you use the same layout (header file) and the modal element exist in HTML of `home/index` (you can use dev tool - f12 for checking)
- Please, Does the modal need to be triggered by a button or something?

Comment: TYWM, i understand my problem. I put js cdn to footer and all is working